# Qual è il significato di "rivoltati" in questa frase?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro autobiografico *Un grande avvenire dietro le spalle* di Vittorio Gassman ho letto:

> Non soffrimmo mai la fame né il freddo, i miei vestiti spesso **rivoltati** suggerivano un'involontaria eleganza démodée, ma non mi diedero mai il complesso vergognoso delle toppe.

Non capisco il senso di "vestiti rivoltati" in questa frase. Ho cercato il [significato di "rivoltare" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/rivoltare/) ed ecco quello che ho trovato di riferente a vestiti:

> *r. la stoffa di un abito, r. una giacca, un cappotto*, mettere al diritto, cioè esternamente, quello che prima era al rovescio, cioè all’interno (e che quindi si è conservato meglio)

Tuttavia, questa definizione non sembra avere molto senso in questo contesto. Cosa ha a che vedere "mettere al diritto un vestito che era al rovescio" con avere "un'eleganza démodée"? Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa "vestiti rivoltati" nel brano precedente?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Un vestito consunto dall'uso poteva essere *rivoltato*, cioè ricucito con l'interno all'esterno. Era molto comune farlo con i cappotti, in modo da prolungarne la durata.

Lo svantaggio era che un vestito rivoltato si notava molto chiaramente, da qui probabilmente il *démodée*: un uso comune un tempo, ma non più tra le classi elevate.